# About PostgreSql JsonB Update?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I want to update in jsonb column.

jsonb columns: field1, area2, area3, area4, area4

I just want to update the field1 and field3 columns.

I found the example but it is updating 1 column.

```
UPDATE table SET jdata = jsonb_set(jdata, '{field1}', '"value"', true)
```

Comment: sorry,
jsonb columns: field1, field2, field3, field4, field5

Comment: Sample data, json and your expected output will be helpful..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table SET jdata = jsonb_set(jsonb_set(jdata, '{field1}', '"value1"', true), '{field2}', '"value2"');
```